How to identify why a particular shared library is needed by an application
I have an application on Linux that I'm building.   The executable unexpectedly needs libQt6OpenGlWidgets.so and some other "stuff".  How can I determine what in my code (or code I am using) causes this to be needed?

You could use ldd, objdump, readelf  and similar, to figure out what symbols are needed from the library and then grep (or git grep) your source code for where it uses that symbol. You may need to demangle (c++filt) some names to make sense of them.

It's unclear that "I'm building" refers to you trying to compile somebody else's code, or your own. In the former case, if the code/project is not properly configured, then you probably need some way to parse/check the whole project for dependencies (and how that's done can depend on many aspects); if it's yours, then you are responsible of adding proper dependencies. We can help you with that, but we can not certainly do that based on vague aspects as "some other stuff" or missing code. Please take your time to review the checklist and provide a [mre].
